# Retrieve running total over time of records in foreign table for each record in table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, window-functions

I have a table `group` and a table `members`. A `group` *has many* `members`. A single `member` record can belong to a single `group`.  The `members` table has a foreign key/column `group_id`.

```
groups
+---------+---------+
|  id     |  name   |
+---------+---------+
| 1       | group01 |
+---------+---------+
```

```
members
+----+---------+------------+
| id | groupid | created_at |
+----+---------+------------+
|  9 |       1 | 2020-03-05 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

I need to retrieve, for each record in the `groups` table, a running total of its member count over time.

Here's an example of what the final data needs to look like, to make this more clear.

```
[
 { group: 'group01', count: 3, date: '2020-01-05' },
 { group: 'group01', count: 10, date: '2020-01-12' },
 { group: 'group01', count: 14, date: '2020-02-02' },
 { group: 'group02', count: 5, date: '2020-01-02' },
 { group: 'group02', count: 13, date: '2020-01-23' },
 { group: 'group02', count: 23, date: '2020-01-28' },
 ...
]
```

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, you can just use window functions for this. You might be able to get the information without even looking at the `groups` table:

```
select
    m.group_id,
    count(*) over(partition by g.group_id order by date) cnt,
    m.date
from members m
```

Or, if you want some data that is available in `groups` but no in `members` (say, the name of the group):

```
select
    g.group_name,
    count(*) over(partition by g.group_id order by date) cnt,
    m.date
from members m
inner join groups g on g.group_id = m.group_id
```